# IntelliJ saying files unsynced after syncing with Bazel

Tags: intellij-idea, bazel

Even after syncing with Bazel, the files are still displaying as "unsynced" in IntelliJ.

I've tried moving to a previous version of Bazel, but to no avail.

Any recommendations here?

Comment: What does your project view file look like?

Comment: Try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart ...` and click `Invalidate and Restart` then check.

Answer (score 8):

Use `Bazel > Sync > Sync Project with BUILD Files` if it is enabled.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your file isn't reachable from the targets specified in the targets: section in .bazelproject file, then it'll show up as unsynced'

Open you .bazelproject file and in under targets:
Specify the path to your file/directory, re sync your project , It should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding the file to git. Sometimes files highlighted in red, or files that say "(unsynced)" next to their name just need to be added to the git branch so that they turn green again.

Answer (score 0):

As @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam mentioned in his comment above, I had to do `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...` Only then, `Bazel > Snyc > Sync Project with BUILD Files` made the unsynced labels finally disappear.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes `Bazel > Sync > Sync Project with BUILD Files` works, sometimes doesn't.

Then I do following, in order:

- Click on any go file do `partially sync <your_file>.go`. If this works fine if not try the next workaround.
- Delete `.idea/` or `.ijwb/` from the project dir works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem with the IntelliJ Bazel plugin. The only workaround that works for me is when I right click any (in my case, the topmost) directory and partially sync by clicking on `Partially Sync <directory>/...:all`.